# What is the difference between imperfect substitutes and complements in a production function?

Tags: microeconomics, production-function

According to the following definition:

```
q-complements/substitutes (q is for quantity).
Input x and y are complements if the marginal product of x is increasing in quantity of y.
Input x and y are substitutes if the marginal product of x is decreasing in quantity of y.
```

Complements are sometimes called "imperfect substitute". See, for instance,[this paper](https://economics.mit.edu/files/11574) (Autor et al. 2003), page 1286-1287.

Comment: Are you sure that definition of q-complements and substitutes applies to production functions? I thought it applied to inverse demand functions.

I believe imperfect substitutes just means there is input substitutability, but the two inputs are not perfect substitutes (MRTS is not a constant).

Comment: See, for instance, [this paper](https://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/aer.20160696) (AER, 2018). Pag 1503, footnote 19, they say:

"For instance, with a constant returns to scale production function and two factors, capital and labor are q−complements. Thus, capital-augmenting technologies always increase the marginal product of labor."